# Kodi Not opening after update today

Tags: updates, permissions, kodi

Kodi is not working after Ubuntu 16.04LTS update today, I uninstalled it  and reinstalled it and still not working. What to do?

```
############## Kodi CRASH LOG ###############

################ SYSTEM INFO ################
 Date: Thu Oct 27 12:59:00 EDT 2016
 Kodi Options: 
 Arch: x86_64
 Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016
 Release: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
############## END SYSTEM INFO ##############

############### STACK TRACE #################
############# END STACK TRACE ###############

################# LOG FILE ##################

12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: special://profile/ is mapped to: special://masterprofile/
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Starting Kodi (16.1 Git:c327c53). Platform: Linux x86 64-bit
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Using Release Kodi x64 build
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Kodi compiled Apr 25 2016 by GCC 5.3.1 for Linux x86 64-bit version 4.4.6 (263174)
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Running on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, kernel: Linux x86 64-bit version 4.4.0-45-generic
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: FFmpeg statically linked, version: 2.8.6-kodi-2.8.6-Jarvis-16.0
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Host CPU: AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1045T Processor, 6 cores available
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: special://xbmc/ is mapped to: /usr/share/kodi
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: special://xbmcbin/ is mapped to: /usr/lib/kodi
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: special://masterprofile/ is mapped to: /home/bandit/.kodi/userdata
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: special://home/ is mapped to: /home/bandit/.kodi
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: special://temp/ is mapped to: /home/bandit/.kodi/temp
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: The executable running is: /usr/lib/kodi/kodi.bin
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Local hostname: bandit-pc
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Log File is located: /home/bandit/.kodi/temp/kodi.log
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: load settings...
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Found 1 Lists of Devices
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Enumerated PULSE devices:
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:     Device 1
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_deviceName      : Default
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_displayName     : Default
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_displayNameExtra: Default Output Device (PULSEAUDIO)
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_deviceType      : AE_DEVTYPE_PCM
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_channels        : FL,FR
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_sampleRates     : 5512,8000,11025,16000,22050,32000,44100,48000,64000,88200,96000,176400,192000,384000
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_dataFormats     : AE_FMT_U8,AE_FMT_S16NE,AE_FMT_S24NE3,AE_FMT_S24NE4,AE_FMT_S32NE,AE_FMT_FLOAT
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:     Device 2
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_deviceName      : alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_displayName     : GF119 HDMI Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI)
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_displayNameExtra: HDMI / DisplayPort (PULSEAUDIO)
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_deviceType      : AE_DEVTYPE_PCM
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_channels        : FL,FR
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_sampleRates     : 5512,8000,11025,16000,22050,32000,44100,48000,64000,88200,96000,176400,192000,384000
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_dataFormats     : AE_FMT_U8,AE_FMT_S16NE,AE_FMT_S24NE3,AE_FMT_S24NE4,AE_FMT_S32NE,AE_FMT_FLOAT
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:     Device 3
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_deviceName      : alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_displayName     : Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_displayNameExtra: Line Out (PULSEAUDIO)
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_deviceType      : AE_DEVTYPE_PCM
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_channels        : FL,FR
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_sampleRates     : 5512,8000,11025,16000,22050,32000,44100,48000,64000,88200,96000,176400,192000,384000
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE:         m_dataFormats     : AE_FMT_U8,AE_FMT_S16NE,AE_FMT_S24NE3,AE_FMT_S24NE4,AE_FMT_S32NE,AE_FMT_FLOAT
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: No settings file to load (special://xbmc/system/advancedsettings.xml)
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Loaded settings file from special://profile/advancedsettings.xml
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Contents of special://profile/advancedsettings.xml are...
                                            <?xml version="1.0" ?>
                                            <advancedsettings>
                                              <loglevel hide="true">-1</loglevel>
                                            </advancedsettings>
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Log level changed to "LOG_LEVEL_NORMAL"
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Default DVD Player: dvdplayer
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Default Video Player: dvdplayer
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Default Audio Player: paplayer
12:58:52 T:140209281395008  NOTICE: Disabled debug logging due to GUI setting. Level -1.


############### END LOG FILE ################

############ END Kodi CRASH LOG #############
```

Comment: I don't have wine  on my computer , also  I purge all of the  kodi files .

Comment: Please open a terminal and run `kodi` from there. Quote the error messages in your question.

Comment: Sorry, .kodi was the folder I meant. Is this the one you deleted?

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'dbiplus::DbErrors'
Aborted (core dumped)
find: ‘/home/bandit/.cache/thumbnails/fail’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/bandit/.cache/dconf’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/bandit/.gvfs’: Permission denied
/usr/bin/kodi: 118: [: |/usr/share/apport: unexpected operator
Crash report available at /home/bandit/kodi_crashlog-20161027_125422.log

Comment: Just a guess: did you run Kodi with sudo or as user root lately?

Comment: Anyway please add your crash log to the question itself. The path is in the error message you posted.

Comment: As a user ,  from unity  icons

Comment: Did you used sudo with other graphical programs? The error message suggests a permission issue your user's folders.

Comment: Well,  I   deleted  the  .Kodi and  reinstall again an it is working  now,  I want to Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by deleting the .kodi folder then:

Purge it like so:

```
sudo apt-get purge xbmc kodi
```

Remove dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install kodi
```